# DLL Injection Keeps Failing with Inconsistent Errors

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, windows, dll-injection

I am attempting to write a DLL Injector in a C# WPF Application. I have written a DLL Injector before in Windows Forms, however I wanted to write a new program from scratch. I have written DLL Injectors before many times in many other languages (using the traditional `VirtualAllocEx` / `WriteProcessMemory` / `CreateRemoteThread` method), however I ran into some peculiar problems. My DLL Injector said that it was succeeding, yet my testing program showed no changes. I did some testing with `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` and got **ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** as a result for `VirtualAllocEx`, `WriteProcessMemory` and `CreateRemoteThread`. I then created an Injector in C++ to test if C# was the problem. When I tested the C++ DLL Injector, every method threw the **ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES** error. Finally, I downloaded my old DLL Injector and found that it no longer works.

I have no idea what the problem is at all.

C# Injector Code:

```cs
IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, SelectedProcess.Id);
Console.WriteLine("OpenProcess: " + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message); // This does not fail.

foreach (string files in DLLFiles.Items) // Get the files from the ListView control
{
    // Allocate memory
    IntPtr address = VirtualAllocEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)(files.Length + 1), AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ExecuteReadWrite);
    Console.WriteLine("VirtualAllocEx: " + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);

    // Write in memory
    if (address != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        bool success = WriteProcessMemory(handle, address, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(files), files.Length + 1, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        Console.WriteLine("WriteProcessMemory: " + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
        if (success)
        {
            IntPtr module = LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll"); // Get the module
            Console.WriteLine("LoadLibrary: " + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
            IntPtr LoadLib = GetProcAddress(module, "LoadLibraryA"); // Get the address of the function
            Console.WriteLine("GetProcAddress: " + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
            // Create a remote thread in the target process
            IntPtr thread_handle = CreateRemoteThread(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, LoadLib, address, 0, out IntPtr lpThreadId);
            Console.WriteLine("CreateRemoteThread: " + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
            if (thread_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.Write("[");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write(files);
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("] Injection Failed: " + new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("[");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write(files);
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("] Injected Successfully.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After running it, the Console said that the injection succeeded yet the error output still kept displaying:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

C++ Injector Code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    DWORD pid = 25860; // Hardcoded for testing purposes.
    std::string str;
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid); // Get the process handle
    std::cout << handle << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    LPVOID addr = VirtualAllocEx(handle, NULL, sizeof("C:\\Users\\BenHerebefore\\source\\repos\\InjectionTest\\InjectionTest\\InjectionTest.dll") + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    std::cout << addr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    BOOL success = WriteProcessMemory(handle, addr, "C:\\Users\\BenHerebefore\\source\\repos\\InjectionTest\\InjectionTest\\InjectionTest.dll", sizeof("C:\\Users\\BenHerebefore\\source\\repos\\InjectionTest\\InjectionTest\\InjectionTest.dll") + 1, NULL);
    std::cout << success << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    HMODULE module = LoadLibrary("kernel32");
    std::cout << module << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    FARPROC proc = GetProcAddress(module, "LoadLibraryA");
    std::cout << proc << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    HANDLE test = CreateRemoteThread(handle, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("kernel32"), "LoadLibrary"), addr, 0, NULL);
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
}
```

The C++ injector displays `Error: 18` after every line. The result for `CreateRemoteThread` returns `0` and the message is `Error: 5`. I tried running the program as Administrator but it still didn't work.

I have absolutely no idea what the problem is.

Comment: You're probably injecting into an elevated process. Try running your injector as admin. Also using sizeof(string) could be wrong. Try strlen and don't forget the \0

Comment: @Nina As mentioned, I already have tried running it as admin. Also, I have already tried using strlen. I believe strings typically have null terminators at the end of them and adding them to the end did nothing anyway. Thanks, though!

Comment: Is your injector/dll the same architecture as the process you are injecting into? For example, if you are injecting into a 64bit process, your dll and your injector should be compiled as x64. Likewsie if it's x86 or WOW64 it should be compiled accordingly.

Comment: @Nina Wow! This worked! Thank you so much for this. I will make sure to accredit you in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Nina's answer, I was compiling it incorrectly. Thanks, Nina!

> Is your injector/dll the same architecture as the process you are injecting into? For example, if you are injecting into a 64bit process, your dll and your injector should be compiled as x64. Likewsie if it's x86 or WOW64 it should be compiled accordingly.